# Reading and outputting image BLOB content C#

Tags: c#

Well, I've searched in numerous places and I cannot find a solution. I have a method that contains blob content that has been retrieved from my database. My problem is that I don't know how I can use the content so that it's displayed in a picture box. The first thing I'm assuming now is that the method must return a byte (which is why I converted it) and then it must be used somehow.

```
    public byte getAvatar()
    {   // row content from database
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
        return Convert.ToByte( row["avatar_blob"] );
    }
```

Past this point, I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) from the `byte[]`:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(yourBytes))
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
    yourPicturebox.Image = bitmap;
}
```

Comment: As for my method, converting it ToByte outputs an error message:  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'. My guess is that converting it is not a great idea...

Comment: Just cast it `(byte[])row["avatar_blob"]`.

Comment: And you're right, coming from PHP, C# is a completely different world. Thanks a bunch!